# Is local DAC enabled by default and does it need to be accessed using -A / Admin:?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I'm trying to understand DAC. Generally this is important when a connection cannot be made to SQL server.

DAC allows and prioritises the admin to remotely connect to SQL server. To use this the remote admin will need to use sqlcmd -A or ssms Admin:.

Suppose if I always have access to the physical server, and DAC is disabled, then is there ever an use case of -A or Admin approach to connect to SQL server? Or is this not applicable for local connections?

Comment: The -A option or Admin connection is typically more relevant when you are trying to establish a remote connection to SQL Server for administrative purposes, especially when regular connections are unavailable or SQL Server is unresponsive due to resource exhaustion or other issues. In a local scenario with physical access to the server, the use of the DAC is less common, as you have more direct methods of accessing and managing SQL Server.